# How to insert in 2 or more tables using Transaction

Tags: transactions, nestjs, typeorm

I need to do some actions that if all pass it commits or all fails.

I know that transactions could do this but I'm having trouble with multiple table inserts.

The [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#transactions) of nestJs says I only need to import the Connect method and create a specific structure but, it does not cover when it's more than 1 table.

NestJs Docu Code:

```js
async createMany(users: User[]) {
    const queryRunner = this.connection.createQueryRunner();

    await queryRunner.connect();
    await queryRunner.startTransaction();

    try {
        await queryRunner.manager.save(users[0]);
        await queryRunner.manager.save(users[1]);
    
        await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
    } catch (err) {
        // since we have errors lets rollback the changes we made
        await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
    } finally {
        // you need to release a queryRunner which was manually instantiated
        await queryRunner.release();
  }
}
```

As you can see all that refers to the User Entity, where does he specify that?

My code:

```js
     const queryR = this.connection.createQueryRunner();
        await queryR.connect();
        await queryR.startTransaction();
    
    
        try {
    
          //## SHIPMENT ENTITY ##
          const shipmentToInsert = Transformador.prepareShipment(ShipConfirmDetails, ShipConfirmSummary)
          //const shipmentInserted = await this.shipmentRepositoryService.insert(shipmentToInsert)//normal insert of entity
          const shipmentInserted = await queryR.manager.save(shipmentToInsert)
    
          //## ORDER ENTITY ##
          const ordersToInsert = Transformador.prepareOrder(ShipConfirmDetails, shipmentInserted.shipment_id)
          const orderedInserted = await queryR.manager.save(ordersToInsert)
    
          //## LINE ENTITY ##
          const linesToInsert = Transformador.prepareLines(ShipConfirmDetails, orderedInserted)
          const linesInserted = await queryR.manager.save(linesToInsert)
    
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(">>Error, se procede a hacer Rollback>>");
          await queryR.rollbackTransaction();
        } finally {
          console.log(">>Se libera Transaction>>");
          await queryR.release();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `entityManager` for create transaction, like this :

```js
export class ExampleTransaction {
    constructor(
        @InjectEntityManager()
        private readonly entityManager: EntityManager,
    ) { }

    public async transactionExampleMethod(): Promise<void> {
        await this.entityManager.transaction(async (transactionalManager: EntityManager) => {
            //## SHIPMENT ENTITY ##
            const shipmentToInsert = Transformador.prepareShipment(ShipConfirmDetails, ShipConfirmSummary);
            const shipmentInserted = await transactionalManager.save(shipmentToInsert);

            //## ORDER ENTITY ##
            const ordersToInsert = Transformador.prepareOrder(ShipConfirmDetails, shipmentInserted.shipment_id)
            const orderedInserted = await transactionalManager.save(ordersToInsert)


            //## LINE ENTITY ##
            const linesToInsert = Transformador.prepareLines(ShipConfirmDetails, orderedInserted)
            const linesInserted = await transactionalManager.save(linesToInsert)
        }
    }
}
```